# ¿Cómo poner teclado numerico en un input password?

Tags: typescript, ionic, input-type

soy nobata en ionic 6 y quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que un input de tipo password acepte sólo valores numericos, ya que todas las contraseñas son "Pines" y por tanto numericos, y quiero que cuando el usuario intente escribir el teclado que se abra sea numerico (Como en el tipo "Tel" ).

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero sigue abriendome el teclado de texto

```
<ion-input
        [type]="showPassword ? 'tel' : 'password'"
        placeholder="Contraseña"
        id="password"
        formControlName="password"
        required
        style="width: 100% !important; height: 100%"
        >
        <ion-icon
          [color]="!fnDisabledButton() ? 'primary' : 'white'"
          slot="start"
          name="lock-closed"
          style="
            font-size: 18px;
            padding-left: 6px;
            padding-right: 6px;
            margin: 0;
          "
        >
        </ion-icon>
      </ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algunos navegadores (iOS) reconocen el valor de atributo de patrón específico de [0-9]* como activación del teclado numérico.

Supuestamente HTML 5.1 contiene el atributo inputmode, que se ha diseñado para abordar el problema específico de la selección del modo de entrada (como el teclado), pero aún no se ha implementado, Esto podrías usarlo en el futuro, aunque el HTML 5.1 actual no lo permite para type=password, por alguna extraña razón.

```html
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```